# flutter: Cancel function after first return statement

Tags: loops, flutter, bluetooth, break, listen

I'm trying to program a bluetooth app with flutter_blue that will only stop searching for devices if a specific device with device name is found. The problem is that the while loop will return multiple device objects instead of only one and stopping the code from there.

Im somhow not able to either break loop, listen() or while function.

So my question: What do I have to do to stop innerloop, listen() and while loop right away after the device was found, so that it only adds one device to the list?

```
Future<void> specificDevice({deviceName: ''}) async {
    // reset values
    _reset();

    // Start scanning and keep on as long as no Device found
    print('Starting search..');

    while (_deviceFound == false) {
      await _flutterBlue.startScan(
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
      );

      _stream = _flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) async {
        print('looking..');

        // Return found Devices
        innerloop:
        for (ScanResult r in results) {
          counter++;
          print('CounterForSchleife: $counter');

          //Does found device equal searched Device?
          if (r.device.name.contains(deviceName)) {
            _deviceFound = true;
            devices.add(r.device);
            print('Device found...');
            _stream.cancel();
            break innerloop;
          }
        }
        if (_deviceFound) {
          print('Broke innerloop');
          // _stream.cancel();
        }
      });
      await _flutterBlue.stopScan();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I solved this issue, by putting the stream listen outside the while loop. it happened to crash the app, at it would continue to start new streams until there were a tone of them. the streams were actually cancelled, but as there were a bunch of them it actually took a while to close all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CancelableOperation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html).

```
test("CancelableOperation with future", () async {

  var cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
    Future.value('future result'),
    onCancel: () => {debugPrint('onCancel')},
  );

// cancellableOperation.cancel();  // uncomment this to test cancellation

  cancellableOperation.value.then((value) => {
    debugPrint('then: $value'),
  });
  cancellableOperation.value.whenComplete(() => {
    debugPrint('onDone'),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, by putting the stream listen outside the while loop. it happened to crash the app, at it would continue to start a new listening to the stream every time the while loop was finished. the streams were actually cancelled, but as there were a bunch of them it actually took a while to close all of them
.